# Hyperledger Fabric Network Set up using Docker or Installed directly

Tags: networking, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Since I am really new to Hyperledger Fabric especially Network Set-up. I try to read the document ,but I didn't the point.
My Scenario is I want to make a small voting system using Block-chain with the implement of Fabric.
I try to install the Fabric v0.6 directly (clone from GIT and use) in my VM local Server without any help of Docker or vagrant ,and successful done it. 
I am also able to run default of peer, membersrvc and some sample example in fabric. by using Postman, all is working fine for me.

Now I want to add more peers(both validating and non-validating) to form a network. Come to this point I try many option is Fabric default document, and some tip is here ,but I still cannot make it. I really appreciate if someone can help me with this part.
- I really want to clear that if It possible or not to form a network using Server directly without the help of Docker or Vagrant. Since some people said that it's not working and some say it works. (Hope to get clear answer here) 
    If can. Could you guide me in it operation (with picture is best)?
    If cannot. Could you guide me the way to make it ?

- I try to follow the [document of fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/Setup/Network-setup/), they are using docker. I try to follow there steps ,but it still not working for me. I still confuse why they are using docker (container) and again they are using vagrant, as my understand both are virtual environment ? **"I hope that someone could pave a way for me this part"**
  Especially with IP address of docker. To connect multiple peer with one VM, it need multiple IPs. I still cannot find a way to easily change IP address of Docker yet?
- Sometimes I successful install vagrant in fabric/devenv ,but While I try to access to hyperledger fabric. I cannot find any resource files.

**My conclusion is that I hope someone can help me in steps ordered on how to make a network in Fabric with easy understand ways. (with Picture or Video is really thankful)**

Comment: Have you tried using docker and editing the configtx.yaml files?

Comment: They have taken the document offline